# Huge query with multiple joins vs Multiple single queries

Tags: mysql, hibernate, rest, jdbc

Suppose there is an Entity

```
public class Subject {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Teacher> teacher;
    private List<Book> books;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Teacher> getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
    public void setTeacher(List<Teacher> teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

}
```

For a Rest API get Subject details in which i would be supplied with an id of subject.

I need to fetch List of Teachers and List of Books along with that then
which is more wise to do Performance wise and flexibility wise.

(1) Single query with joins
(2) 1 query for User then 1 query for teacher with subject_id as filter then 1 query for book with subject_id as filter

Please do consider performance, Entity building logic and flexibility to changes into consideration for eg. in same API user may provide a flag to tell whether to include Book list or not in response.
Also how it is decided in enterprise projects which method to use.

Comment: In general, the fewer round trips to the database the better, but whenever uncertainty arises, a simple test would provide the answer

Comment: The only answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends...

- How many `Teacher` by `Subject` in the worst case?
- How many `Book` by `Subject` in the worst case?
- How many `Subject` in the worst case?
- Are there other linked entities?

If the responses are `10, 50, 1000, no`, the result could return 500 000 rows (10*50*1000)!

Well you should consider the Cartesian product

If the Cartesian product is not a problem, Joins are faster.